# Java combination of Set and List interfaces

Tags: java, list, collections, set

I have a data structure, for which I am currently using an `ArrayList`. I realised that in this structure I do not want any duplicates to be present. My first thought was to use some form of set, however the order is also important. After a bit of googling and searching the Collections docs I found `LinkedHashSet` which almost does the job. Unfortunately, one of the primary reasons for preserving order is because I am using the `get(int index)` method of the ArrayList for random access, and I can't see any way around this.

More concisely - I need a set that preserves order and allows random access. None of the classes I have so far looked at provide this functionality. Does anyone know of a class that offers this, or will I have to make it myself? If it is the latter case are there any pitfalls when creating such a structure that people are aware of?

(Alternatively, a quick and easy way of checking for and removing duplicates form an ArrayList or similar structure would suffice)

EDIT: for clarity, it is the order that elements are added to the list that is important, not how they compare to one another

Comment: Use a TreeMap<Integer,YourObject>.

Comment: you could use a bidirectional map between your type and integers.  http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html  That way, you can ensure uniqueness, and have fast lookup.  You will need a global counter for new integer keys though.

Comment: @Maurício: this won't work. Map allows duplicate values. The restriction is on the key only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just extend `ArrayList`.

```
public class SetList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return contains(e) ? false : super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, E e) {
        if (!contains(e)) {
            super.add(index, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        return addAll(size(), c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        Collection<E> copy = new ArrayList<E>(c);
        copy.removeAll(this);
        return super.addAll(index, copy);
    }

}
```

Note that the `add()` method conforms [the contract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29):

> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation). Returns `true` if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns `false` if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)

Comment: If a client used this type as a List, could they insert duplicates that would break the Set contract that duplicates are eliminated?

Comment: That would be quite inneficient: ArrayList.contains() does a sequential search; that is, if you have a million elements, and need to add one more, you'll have to do a million comparisons.

Answer (score 10):

[`SetUniqueList`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html) from commons-collections:

```
List<Foo> uniqueList = SetUniqueList.decorate(new ArrayList<Foo>());
```

(unfortunately, commons-collections still doesn't support generics, so you'll have to suppress a warning here)

Comment: It uses an internal Set to do the existance checking, so it's a good enough solution in terms of speed, even though it'll spend a bit of additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a subclass of AbstractList that keeps an ArrayList as its backing store, overrides most methods to delegate them to the backing store, and overrides `add()` to reject duplicates?

```
class NoDupesList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    private final List<E> backing;

    NoDupesList() {
        backing = new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public E get(int index) {
        return backing.get(index);
    }

    // ...

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return backing.contains(o);
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (contains(e))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicates disallowed: " + e):

        return backing.add(e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: sets don't thrown exceptions. They replace the element.

Comment: If you are going this route, and memory efficiency isn't paramount, you can keep both an `ArrayList` and a `HashSet` as backing stores. If you go this route, only the remove operations -- `remove(int)` and `remove(Object)` etc -- will be O(n).

Comment: Duh :P Ok I was being very thick I can just extend ArrayList and ovveride add() to reject duplicates, I don't even need the backing list. This answer pointed this out to me.

Comment: @Bozho true -- however, add() stipulates raising IllegalArgumentException if some property of the element prevents it from being added to the list. I considered its equivalence to some other element of the list such a property. Debatable, perhaps.

Comment: @James note that without an additional set structure, the `contains` call in `add(E e)` will be O(n). Also, the default `set` method could cause problems if you change an element to one that already exists elsewhere.

Comment: @Vlad Thank you for pointing that out. O(n) should be good enough (though I'll change it if it becomes too slow, but I cannot foresee more than a couple of hundred elements. And I will have to go through and override set, add and any other methods that may cause an issue, but as I am making the structure for a specific purpose again this should not be problematic.

Comment: If you're using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), extending [ForwardingList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html) might help minimize the boilerplate.

Comment: This `add()` method doesn't conform the method's contract. It should not throw an exception on duplicate, but just return `false`. Note that there are in total 4 `add` methods which needs to be implemented.

Comment: I agree with BalusC. This is exactly why it's better to prefer composition over inheritance. Also `add` throwing an exception violates the `Collection` contract. Take a look at `Collection.add(Object)`, in particular the third paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList and a HashMap together:

```
import java.util.*;

class AS<T>{

    private HashMap<T, Integer> m = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    private ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add(T object){
        if (!m.containsKey(object)){
            m.put(object, a.size());
            a.add(object);
        }
    }
    public void remove(T object){
        Integer i = m.get(object);
        if (i!=null){
            a.remove(i.intValue());
            m.remove(object);
        }
    }
    public void remove(int index){
        m.remove(a.get(index));
        a.remove(index);
    }
    public T get(int index){
        return a.get(index);
    }

    public String toString(){return a.toString();}
}
```

Comment: it would be nicer if the collection implemented the `List` interface