# Why is there no random access set in java.util

Tags: java, list, collections, set

Why doesn't there exist a class in the standard library that implements both the `Set` and the `List` interfaces? Linked set retains the order of a set but doesn't allow random access.

Why isn't this seen as useful?

Comment: Why don't you write one?  There's nothing magic about the implementations of the current stuff -- you can do anything they can do.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780813/java-combination-of-set-and-list-interfaces

Comment: I know that "there is now magic" and yes I can and have implemented it myself. This question is out of mere interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's extremely hard to implement efficiently, for one, at least if you're supporting removes.  For example, Guava's `ImmutableSet` supports random access via its `asList()` view, but doesn't support mutation.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is impossible to do so without breaking the contract of `Set`or `List`. A `Set`may not hold duplicates. What happens if you use the container as a `List` and try to add a duplicate?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035008/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-list